# How to improve Blessed vs Cursed duel deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I bought [Blessed vs Cursed](http://magic.wizards.com/en/content/duel-decks-blessed-vs-cursed) as my first contact with magic. I've played with friends to the point I regret not buying card sleeves (I played ~40 games of ~60 games played in total). I also went to my local store and they let me play with other decks.

I'm going to the prerelease of karesh so I'm starting there building a deck and playing with the locals. But there are lots of fiends I love to play with, they already love the game (after playing with Blessed vs Cursed) but have no money to spend.

I want to still play with the Blessed vs Cursed decks with friends, but having 'more fun cards'. What I mean is a more complex set of cards. Playing with decks in the shop, all have a strategy in mind and it was a bit more complex and interesting.

My experience with the duel deck, usually when one of the two is winning there is little the other can do. The matches usually are a bit short. I got the feeling they are balanced because I won with either one with no problem.

I think some problems could be consistency in the hands, yesterday playing with a friend I won 3 out of 4. Because he was really unlucky and there was little he can do.

My plan for both decks:

Blessed:

I want to take advantage of this combination:

> Champion of the Parish and Gather the Townsfolk with blinking.

Something in this line when blessed improves on some warriors and creates some extra weak forces but great in number. I don't know if increasing the number of copies will create this effect.

Cursed:

We don't seem to find any place for Cobbled Wings or Driver of the Dead, and we like the horde of zombies cursed could bring to the table, but we like more zombies.

Adding more Gravecrawler and Moan of the Unhallowed.

I want to go to the shop with an idea this week and expand this month card budget in this idea. But I don't know if it's any good or it's just plain stupid. Also having so many cards available to buy, I just want some guidance and advice. **Is my idea any good or reasonable?**

To clarify my question. **Based on my idea to improve [Blessed vs Cursed](http://magic.wizards.com/en/content/duel-decks-blessed-vs-cursed) is there any there is any card (or list of cards) I should take into account?** I'm looking to show more of what magic has to offer just with this two decks.

Other things I'll experience are Planeswalkers, there is fun to play with. But the decks have none.

Some cards I've seen:

- Battlewise Hoplite
- Diregraf Colossus
- Endless Ranks of the Dead

Comment: I recommend going to tappedout.net for this type of assistance; the question is too subjective for this website.

Comment: I'm trying to ask about some basic principles when thinking of a new deck based on my idea. Thanks @GendoIkari for the web, I'm asking over there.

Comment: When you get enough rep you can also join us in chat. We have several Magic players that frequent our room that could help with things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Finding combos and abusing them is the way to go. However, mtg is a very p2p game. Look into a format called pauper that uses only commons for a cheap way to get in. Also, vampires and madness can be made for standard cheaply with onli shadows over innistrad and Erdrich moon.